# How can i change color in a table when i changes values in the table? I get the values from db with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When I click on the `checkbox` and the value of that row changes or when i add a new workout and the table changes i want it to change color... I don't know how to proceed.

Please help me :)

I think it could be something like this:  `$('#TblWorkouts input').on('change'`  but I'm don't know.

Jag har en uppgift att lämna in där ett krav är att när en rad i tabellen ändras ska den få en annan färg men jag vet inte hur jag ska gå till väga.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

   

   
    <script>

        *$('#TblWorkouts input').on('change'  <!--- how to make the table row change color when a value has been changed or a new row have been added?  -->*

        function getAllWorkouts() {
            $.getJSON("./index1.php/controller/getWorkouts", function (jsondata){
                showWorkoutsInTable(jsondata);
            });
        }



            function addWork() {

                let workoutet=$("#textWork").val();

               // var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();
               let donet=$("#CheckDone:checked").val();
                alert(donet);


                $.post("./index1.php/controller/addWorkout",{workout:workoutet, done:donet}, function (jsondata) {
                    alert(jsondata['klar']);
                })
                getAllWorkouts();

        }

        function updateWorkout() {
            let idt=$("#txtId").val();

            let donet=$("#done:checked").val();

            $.post("./index1.php/controller/updateWorkout",{id:idt, done:donet}, function (jsondata) {
                alert(jsondata['svar']);
            });

        }

        function showWorkoutsInTable(jsondata) {
            let table=$("#TblWorkouts");
            table.empty();
            $.each(jsondata, function(idx, workout){
                table.append("<tr>");
                table.append("<td>"+workout['id']+" </td>");
                table.append("<td>"+workout['workout']+" </td>");
                table.append("<td>"+workout['date']+" </td>");
                if(workout['done']==1){
                    table.append("<td> <input onclick='updateWorkout()' type=\"checkbox\" checked value='1' id=\"done\">Ja</input></td>");
                }
                else{
                    table.append("<td> <input onclick='updateWorkout()' type=\"checkbox\" value='1' id=\"done\">Ja</input></td>");
                }
                table.append("<td>"+workout['done']+"</td>");
                table.append("</tr>");

            })

        }

               $(document).ready(function(){
            getAllWorkouts();
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Tittis träning</h1>
</div>


<addForm style="width:25%" >
    <label> Träning: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textWork" required>
    <label for="checkDone">Utförd: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckDone" value="1" >Ja</input>

    <button onclick="addWork()" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till</button>
</addForm>

<br>
<table class="table" id="TblWorkouts" style="max-width: 50%">


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In another words, are you asking how to use the [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method?

Comment: Yes i think so, how can i use the change method so when it feels a change it changes the color for that row :) So yes please :D

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure how to look at your snippet (what it's suppose to do),
here is a simple usage of `change` method to toggle a class on the first row which will color it with red.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  $('tr:first-child').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
tr.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row #2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row #3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can do this easily with css only, without script (which is always better).

```css
input:checked + table tr:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row #2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row #3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can read more about `:checked` selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

Comment: You are so fantastic for helping me. Its a workout site, where i can type in a work out. And use the check box for if i hade done the workout or not. When i click the checkbox my Db (use mySql) changes the value of "done" to 1 and if the checkbox is not checked the db changes the value to 0, and if the value is zero from the db the checkbox in the table should be unchecked. And when something changes, if i check on or uncheck one or add a new workout that change should highlight in the table. So i dont want all checked checkboxes to go red. Only the row that have been changed.